# OOP different objects need to run different methods (Java)

Tags: java, oop, jpanel

I am creating a GUI for a simple game by creating a subclass of JPanel. I've decided to create my own buttons that will do something when clicked. However, fundamentally, each button should do something different to pretty much every other button when pressed.

How should I go about giving each button a separate action? The immediate solution that comes to mind is to create a different class for every single button I make, however that doesn't seem right OOP-wise and work-per-button-created-wise, is there a better way accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you are using your own buttons, you could still adapt the pattern used by swing's [`JButton`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html). With `JButton` you have a separate `ActionListener` class to execute the action (or multiple actions if you add more listeners). This way you can have a common buttons class that is responsible for it's design and being clickable, but delegates any interaction to the listeners. On a click, it will just call all action listener's `actionPerformed` methods to execute the actual actions.

In swing setting up a button would look like this:

```
JButton button = new JButton();
ActionListener action = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
      // do something
    }
};
button.addActionListener(action);
```

You don't have too manage multiple action listeners of course, using a single action per button might be enough.

Comment: Is there a way to use ActionListener for my listener, or do I have to start from scratch?

Comment: @Eykar `ActionListener` is just a simple interface with one method, but I guess you could use it if you want to. If you ignore the ActionEvent, you only need to create a setter to add the listener to the button and also the call to perform the action. Is there a reason why you can't just use `JButton`? That would be easier.

Comment: I am drawing images in paintComponent, I wanted the consistency of drawing the buttons in the same way.

Comment: You can do that with JButton too. You can extends `JButton` and override `paintComponent`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407024/drawing-graphics-on-top-of-a-jbutton