# Defining a background color and a foreground icon for a JButton?

Tags: java, swing, computer-science

I'm working on a Fire Emblem mock up using Swing (which I'm just getting the hang of, I used to work mostly on console programs). To those who are not familiar with the game, it's a tile based strategy game where you move units on a grid (akin to chess).

[image: Example]

I'm thinking about using JButtons for the grid, so that the player is able to click on the unit he wants to move, and click on his destination. As you can see on the picture, the tile color behind the unit can vary (red means the unit can attack the unit on that tile, blue means a tile where the selected unit can move). I don't want to have 15 different tile designs for each unit (UnitX with blue background, UnitX with red background, UnitX with green background, etc.) so is there a way to use "layers" with JButtons? Draw a blue tile and draw the correct character over it?

Comment: This might be useful for what you're trying to do 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407024/drawing-graphics-on-top-of-a-jbutton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from [camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131872/camickr) is correct (assuming that I've understood your question).

The following code demonstrates how you can use `setBackground` and `setIcon` on a `JButton`. It shows one button with a background color and an icon. The button changes its background color when it's clicked:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;

public class ButtonBackgroundAndIcon {
    private static final List<Color> BACKGROUND_COLORS = Arrays.asList(
            new Color(229, 119, 120),
            Color.BLUE,
            Color.CYAN,
            Color.GREEN,
            Color.YELLOW,
            Color.RED
    );

    private int backgroundIndex;

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ButtonBackgroundAndIcon()::run);
    }

    private void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Stack Overflow");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton tileButton = new JButton();
        tileButton.setBackground(BACKGROUND_COLORS.get(0));

        Icon icon = getRoyIcon();
        if (icon != null) {
            tileButton.setIcon(icon);
        }

        tileButton.addActionListener(actionEvent -> {
            backgroundIndex = (backgroundIndex + 1) % BACKGROUND_COLORS.size();
            tileButton.setBackground(BACKGROUND_COLORS.get(backgroundIndex));
        });

        frame.getContentPane().add(tileButton);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private ImageIcon getRoyIcon() {
        ImageIcon imageIcon;

        try {
            String iconLocation = "http://orig06.deviantart.net/fd0e/f/2008"
                                  + "/060/d/1/roy_sprite_by_chstuba007.gif";
            imageIcon = new ImageIcon(new URL(iconLocation));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            imageIcon = null;
        }

        return imageIcon;
    }
}
```

Comment: (1-) as you said the answer has already been given. No need to repeat the answer. No need to write code. All the OP has to do is add the two lines of code to their current program to test the solution.

Answer (score 4):

> Draw a blue tile and draw the correct character over it?

1. Use the `setBackground(...)` method to set the background 
   color.
2. Use the `setIcon(...)` method to set the character.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming if you have a transparent image you can use this class to accomplish what you desire.

public class ColorBackgroundIcon implements Icon {

```
private ImageIcon image;
private Color background;

public ColorBackgroundIcon(ImageIcon image, 
                           Color background) {
    this.image = image;
    this.background = background;
}

@Override
public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g.setColor(background);
    g.fillRect(x, y, getIconWidth(), getIconHeight());
    g2d.drawImage(image.getImage(), x, y, null);

}

public void setColor(Color bgColor) {
    this.background = bgColor;
}

@Override
public int getIconWidth() {
    return image.getIconWidth();
}

@Override
public int getIconHeight() {
    return image.getIconHeight();
}
```

}

Then just setIcon() using a instance created above. Works great for me since I have four states a certain icon can represent. Instead of creating four different icons I have one transparent icon and I change the background with the code provided.

Hope that helps for anyone, 
DK